# Error E2093 c++

Tags: c++, compilation

I'am receiving this weird error i have never seen it before and don't even know what it means, please give me a hand on it...

```
 #include<iostream>
    #include<map>
    #include<algorithm>
    using namespace std;
    class Person
{
  private:
   int code;
   string name;
  public:  
   Person(int cod,string nom);
   void setcode(int cod);
   void setname(string nom);
   int getcode();
   string getname();
};
    Person::Person(int cod,string nom){code=cod;name=nom;}
    void Person::setcode(int cod){code=cod;}
    void Person::setname(string nom){name=nom;}
    int Person::getcode(){return code;}
    string Person::getname(){return name;}

    int main ()
{
  map<Person,string>human;

  human.insert(make_pair(Person(15,"LewinVillar"),"primero"));
  human.insert(make_pair(Person(17,"GeanSosa"),"segundo"));
  human.insert(make_pair(Person(20,"WillyRamos"),"tercero"));
  human.insert(make_pair(Person(35,"WillyRojas"),"cuarto"));
  human.insert(make_pair(Person(40,"CuchoSalas"),"quinto"));

}
```

This is the error im getting

```
Error E2093 C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\stl/_function_base.h 73: 'operator<' not implemented in type 'Person' for arguments of the same typ
const Person &,const Person &) const
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear?!? ...

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong but if do not specify the arrage function it should take the default one, i had use a code pretty alike before and i didn't use it...

Comment: map<Employee,string>MapEmployee,MapDB;
    map<Employee,string>::iterator iter1,iter2,element;
  pair<map<Employee,string>::iterator,bool>Added;
  string Win,name,count;
  fstream DataReadDB("DB.bin",ios::in);
   if(!DataReadDB){cerr<<"No Se Pudo Abrir El Archivo Boost.bin Para Lectura";}
     while(!DataReadDB.eof())
  {
          DataReadDB>>Win>>name>>count;
    MapDB.insert(make_pair(Employee(Win,name,count),"no")); 
        }
    DataReadDB.close();

Comment: There is no default `operator<` for user-defined types. You need to provide one.

Comment: @user3423649 Looks like `Employee` does have `operator<` defined and for `std::pair` there's a default implementation available which then calls the member's `operator<` - for `Person`, you still need to define one. There is no "default" one for any class you write. Of course you could replace map's default of `std::less<Person>` with something else to avoid having to use `operator<`, but you still need to define an order. As I said in my answer: There are several options.

Comment: @user3423649 Please add essential informations to your question, not in comments. Especially if it's code!!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The error message is clear only wrt the symptom, but the underlying question was who requires `operator<` and *why*.

Comment: @DanielFrey Though adding additional (code) information in comments, isn't that much useful.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's true. :) My comment was more targeted at the first comment you made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a type as a key in a `std::map`, the map requires `operator<` to sort the elements it contains. You need to add:

```
friend inline bool operator<( const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs )
{
    return lhs.code < rhs.code;
}
```

(or something other appropriate) to your class. It could also be a free function after the class if you use the getters for `code`, there are several options.